# Consume only from a specific routing key in Spring cloud stream with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-rabbit

In Cloud Stream for RabbitMQ I want to set a consumer that will consume from a Queue only the messages that have been forwarded with a specific routing key. Is this possible?

Here are my application.properties.

**Producer**:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer.bindQueue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer.declareExchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.producer1-out-0.destination=exchange1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.producer1-out-0.producer.routingKeyExpression='routing.key.1'
```

**Consumer**:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer.bindQueue=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer.declareExchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer1-in-0.destination=exchange1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer1-in-0.group=reports
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.consumer1-in-0.consumer.queueNameGroupOnly=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.consumer1-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKeyDelimiter=,
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.consumer1-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey='routing.key.1'
```

Exchanges and bindings are defined directly in RabbitMQ.

My expectation was if I change `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.consumer1-in-0.consumer.bindingRoutingKey` to something else the consumer will stop consuming but it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; unlike JMS, RabbitMQ has no concept of a message selector; you will get all messages.

The canonical way to solve this issue is to use a different queue for each RK.

`bindingRoutingKey` is meaningless when `bindQueue` is false and, in any case, all it does is specify which routing key to use when binding the queue to the exchange.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I ended up creating separate Queues and Bindings for each type of routing key. Although consumers can subscribe to more then one Queues there is no way to listen only to some of the queue's messages, as you said.